# Executing Matlab script via COM API from Java

Tags: java, matlab

I'm having trouble getting my Matlab script to execute using the COM API calling from Java. Here's a Java unit test:

```
import com.jacob.activeX.ActiveXComponent;
import com.jacob.com.Variant;

@Test
public void testMatlab()
{
   ActiveXComponent myMatlabInCom = new ActiveXComponent("Matlab.Application");
   myMatlabInCom.invoke("Execute", new Variant("addpath('C:\\mike\\test');"));
   myMatlabInCom.invoke("Execute", new Variant("cd ('C:\\mike\\test');"));
   myMatlabInCom.invoke("Execute", new Variant("testScript;"));
}
```

Here's my Matlab testScript.m file:

```
function testScript()

prompt = 'Do you want more? Y/N [Y]: ';
str = input(prompt,'s');
if isempty(str)
    str = 'Y';
end

disp('You answered: ');
disp(str);
```

testScript.m is in the 'c:\mike\test' folder

The behavior I'm seeing is that the prompt never shows up.  It seems as though my script is never called.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Seems like this should be easy but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks, -Mike

Comment: Could you provide the code which executes your script?

Comment: Updated the sample to be a junit test